# Shiny - puts HTML modal on pending

Tags: r, shiny

I have following workflow:

- app starts and loads start page
- it tries to load some libraries, if they are not installed, their names will be saved in a variable
- a message about installing missing packages will be sent to the js side-> the js side will open a bootstrap modal with the message `please waite`
- during this time, the needed packages will be installed

**server.r:**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    sendMessage <- function(message) {
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'message', message = message);
    }



   repo <- "http://cran.rstudio.com/";

   missingPackages <- c()
   missingPackages <- c(missingPackages, tryCatch({library(mvoutlier)}, error = function(e) {return("mvoutlier")}));
   missingPackages <- c(missingPackages, tryCatch({library(robCompositions)}, error = function(e) {return("robCompositions")}));
   missingPackages <- c(missingPackages, tryCatch({library(VIM)}, error = function(e) {return("VIM")}));
   missingPackages <- c(missingPackages, tryCatch({library(StatDA)}, error = function(e) {return("StatDA")}));
   missingPackages <- c(missingPackages, tryCatch({library(robustbase)}, error = function(e) {return("robustbase")}));
   missingPackages <- c(missingPackages, tryCatch({library(MASS)}, error = function(e) {return("MASS")}));
   missingPackages <- c(missingPackages, tryCatch({library(mclust)}, error = function(e) {return("mclust")}));

  if (length(missingPackages) > 0) {
     print(missingPackages);
     sendMessage(c("missingPackages", missingPackages));

     unableToInstall <- "";
     for (i in seq(along = missingPackages)) {
         tryCatch({
             install.packages(missingPackages[i], repo = repo, dependencies = T);
         }, error = function(e) {
             delimitation <- "";
             if (unableToInstall != "") {
                 delimitation <- ", ";
             }

             unableToInstall <- paste0(unableToInstall, delimitation, missingPackages[i])
         })
     }
})
```

**js - side:**

```
angular.module('r').service('rService', function($rootScope, $uibModal) {

   Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('message', function(message) {
     switch (message[0]) {
         case "missingPackages": {
             $uibModal.open({
                 --- options ---
              })
         }
      }
   });
});
```

my **problem** is the fact that my modal is not opened before starting to install the packages.

I commented the line with the `install. ...` and my modal appeared instantaneously.

I also tried to set a `Sys.sleep(5)` but that didn't helped me.

**update:**

I saw in the browser developer console, that my modal is set on `pending` while the packages are being installed, this means that `Shiny` pauses the rest of the workflow.

Comment: I can't really run your exact code to reproduce, but I just tried replacing your `sendMessage` line with `shinyjs::info()` (which shows a simple javascript dialog), and it did show it before attempting to install.  Maybe trying using `shinyjs` (you'll have to add a call to `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` in your UI)

Comment: @daattali 'sendMessage' is just a wrapper for 'session$sendCustomMessage()'. I've got 'session$sendCustomMessage("message", msg)' in 'server.R' and in my js file I've got 'Shiny.addCustomMessage("message", msg)'

Comment: But it is strange that if I '#' the 'install.packages' part, everything wokrs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by sending an `event` after the modal loads and just after receiving the `event`, the package installation starts.

**js - side:**

```
angular.module('r').service('rService', function($rootScope, $uibModal){

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('message', function(message) {
   switch (message[0]) {
     case "missingPackages": {
         var _modal = $uibModal.open({
             --- options ---
          });
          _modal.opend.then(function(){
             Shiny.onInputChange("installMissingPackages", true);
          });
     }
    }
  });
});
```

**server.R:**

```
observeEvent(input$installMissingPackages, {
   --- installing packages ---
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I can't replicate your problem because you aren't providing a full reproducible example. Here's a minimal working shiny app that tries to mimic what you're doing, but I'm using shinyjs to send the message (I did it for convenience, but it seems that maybe it fixes your problem too?)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  "hello"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  missingPackages <- c("thisdoes", "notexist")
  info(missingPackages)

  for (i in seq(along = missingPackages)) {
    tryCatch({
      Sys.sleep(3)
      logjs("attempting to install")
      logjs(missingPackages[i])
      cat("attempting to install", missingPackages[i])
      install.packages(missingPackages[i]);
    }, error = function(e) {
      cat("error")
    })
  }
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `logjs` statements cause the text to be shown in the JS console in your browser, it's just there so you can see when each package is getting installed

Comment: I'm using `server.R` and `index.html` so I'm not using `ui.R`. I updated my code.

Comment: oh geez, that complicates things. If you go to the shinyjs readme on github, it'll tell you how to include it in an index.html app, it's easy too. But it looks like your example is still quite complicated, I'd suggest you try to get a minimal reproducible example that's simple and removes all other factors (looks like you're using some other JS libraries too), that'll make it easier for us to answer and easier for you to debug. Really hard to help when your example is complicated and has lots of unrelated bits